# Retrieve a specific word from the entire string in android?

Tags: android, regex

I have some data in the html format. I am using Html.fromHtml(String) when setting the data to the textview in android. Also the html data contains 2 to 3 images. I want to get the name of the images from the html data and  store them in an array. Based on the number of the images in the array I will set them to the imageview. How can I get the image name from src in image tag?

*Which one will be the better option .i.e using regular expression or substring?*

Please suggest some solutions and help me with some examples.

My Code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ 
---
---
   desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
   URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(desc, this);
   Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(listItem.getdesc(), p, null);
   desc.setText(htmlSpan);
----
----
----
----
}


public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        // the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
        // with the loading image if you need to
        protected Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
            if(drawable != null) {
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }



    public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
        ListAdapter c;
        View container;

        /***
         * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the container
         * @param t
         * @param listAdapter
         */
        public URLImageParser(View t, ListAdapter listAdapter) {
            this.c = listAdapter;
            this.container = t;
        }

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

            // get the actual source
            ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
                new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

            asyncTask.execute(source);

            // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
            // the src tag
            return urlDrawable;
        }

        public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  {
            URLDrawable urlDrawable;

            public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
                this.urlDrawable = d;
            }

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                String source = params[0];
                return fetchDrawable(source);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                        + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 

                // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                // from the HTTP call
                urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
            }

            /***
             * Get the Drawable from URL
             * @param urlString
             * @return
             */
            public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                            + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
                    return drawable;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                } 
            }

            private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.ImageGetter()` will be more helpful, it will find the tag `<img>`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply...I have gone through Html.imagegetter examples. All of those I found getting the image from drawable. Actually all my images are stores in server becoz they are of large size. So now I need to get those images asynchronously from server and set them to textview using imagegetter method. How can I achieve this task?

Comment: you can do that by append server prefix filename `xxxx.imagefile.png` create image in `doInBackground`.

Comment: @user1455252 Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask

Comment: Hi I have gone through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask and done same like that. But instead of Context in
URLImageParser class constructor I kept ListAdapter. Its because I am setting the text in the listview and so I created the object for the class in getview method.
But finally the image is not displaying, only the test is displaying. Please suggest me where I went wrong..I kept my code..please check once.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the name of the images

If you are using jsoup html parser then life is much easier.

I dont know how images names are apperaing in HTML data.

But suppose your html has images as follows

```
<img src='image_url/abc.png'>

File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]").first();

String imageurl= pngs.attr("src"); which will return
```

> image_url/abc.png

I have posted example snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026937/parsing-particular-data-from-website-in-android/11026988#11026988)