# Getting the image from html data in android?

Tags: android

Hi I have gone through the link [Android HTML ImageGetter as AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask) to set the image for html data. When I executed the below code it is displaying the o/p as Hello This is a test and then again it is replacing "This is a test" to img1 and also the second image is not displayed. Please suggest me HOW CAN i PLACE THE IMAGE NEXT TO THE TEXT?

Thanks in advance

My Code:

```
  main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="10pt" >
        </TextView>

</LinearLayout>

Myclass.java

public class SamplehtmlActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView textView;
    String html = "Hello " +
    "<img src='http://server.com/img1.png'/>" +
    " This is a test " +
    "<img src='http://server.com/img2.png'/>";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv_pw);
        URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(textView, this);
        Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(html, p, null);
        textView.setText(htmlSpan);

    }

    public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        // the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
        // with the loading image if you need to
        protected Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
            if(drawable != null) {
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }


    public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
        Context c;
        View container;

        /***
         * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the container
         * @param t
         * @param c
         */
        public URLImageParser(View t, Context c) {
            this.c = c;
            this.container = t;
        }

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

            // get the actual source
            ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
                new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

            asyncTask.execute(source);

            // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
            // the src tag
            return urlDrawable;
        }

        public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  {
            URLDrawable urlDrawable;

            public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
                this.urlDrawable = d;
            }

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                String source = params[0];
                return fetchDrawable(source);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                        + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 

                // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                // from the HTTP call
                urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
            }

            /***
             * Get the Drawable from URL
             * @param urlString
             * @return
             */
            public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                            + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
                    return drawable;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                } 
            }

            private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying for? Want to display the image from URL

Comment: yes..my data is stored in html format. So I am referring the image in the image tag with src='http://server.com/img1.png'. When I set the data to textview it is displaying the text but the image is replaced on the text. How can I make the image display next to text instead of displaying on the text

Comment: You're reading some html contents from some api right?

Comment: yes...my data is stored in database and I am getting the data from that db.

Comment: So, you're having the image path in your database? After getting it and stored into your `Database`

Comment: yes...please suggest me the solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12546/discussion-between-user1448108-and-spk)