# HTML images in TextView with percent width

Tags: android, android-asynctask, html-parsing, drawable, textview

I'm trying to show content (text and images) in a TextView. It works very well by this method: [Android HTML ImageGetter as AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask)

But sometime images are larger then width of screen.
How can I force images to use percentage width?

EDIT: The percent width value is not important, I just want to see images with equal scale on each screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that is programmatically.
To change the `Bitmap` size see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android).
To get sreen size see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions).
To get View size you must use in post method:

```
yourView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int h = yourView.getHeight();
        int w = yourView.getWidth();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use percentage width. Accepted units are (quoted from the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_width)):

> Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp
>   (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm
>   (millimeters).

I think it is possible to set the width programmatically based on screen size, though I'm not aware of the calculations needed.