# Android Images are stretched when the phone is rotated

Tags: android

I am getting images using the Html.fromHtml() method. So I am using URLImageParser and URLDrawable classes as defined here: [Android HTML ImageGetter as AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask).

I have adapted two methods from URLImageParser in order to scale the image to the width of the screen whilst maintaining the aspect ratio. The changed methods are as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {


        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = width * container.getHeight() / container.getWidth();


        urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+width, 0+height);  

        // change the reference of the current drawable to the result 
        // from the HTTP call 
        urlDrawable.drawable = result; 

        // redraw the image by invalidating the container 
        URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

        // For ICS
        URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight() 
        + height));

        // Pre ICS
        URLImageParser.this.container.setEllipsize(null);
    }
```

and

```
    public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
        try {


            InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int width = dm.widthPixels;
            int height = width * container.getHeight() / container.getWidth();


            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + width, 0 
                    + height); 
            return drawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } 
    }
```

My problem is that when the phone is held in portrait orientation the image looks fine. However when I rotate the phone the width of the image goes to the new width of the phone, however the height does not change so the image looks distorted.

Is there a way to reset the height when the phone is rotated?

Pretty sure this is a silly mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

To detect a screen rotation, you can try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[See more](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Handling-Orientation-in-Android).

Here is [another great example](http://techblogon.com/android-screen-orientation-change-rotation-example/).