# UrlImageParser in RecyclerView ViewHolder - no context

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem, I am using this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442725/3569225 to make images url automatically change to images.
But when I try to create the URLImageParser I need to give him context.
I am doing this in the ViewHandler and I dont have there getApplicationContext command.
This is the code I am trying to do:
`@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   ...
   UrlImageParser p = new UrlImageParser(holder.message, this);
   holder.message.setText(Html.fromHtml(MessageItems.get(position).getMessage()));
   ...
}`

I need to replace 'this' with the context, But I dont have it, What can I do?

Comment: pass your context to constructor of Adapter Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow sample example to understand how to pass a context to an adapter.

```
private Context context; 
public myAdapter(Context context,....){  
    this.context = context;  
}
```

Now you can use the context from anywhere inside of your adapter.

Comment: OK, but the image url doesn't became to image :(