# Displaying image in original size using TextView and ImageGetter

Tags: android, image, html-parsing, textview

[I use code from this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask)

```
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
Context c;
TextView container;

/***
 * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the container
 * @param t
 * @param c
 */
public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    this.container = t;
}

public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

    // get the actual source
    ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
        new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

    asyncTask.execute(source);

    // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
    // the src tag
    return urlDrawable;
}

public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  {
    URLDrawable urlDrawable;

    public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
        this.urlDrawable = d;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        String source = params[0];
        return fetchDrawable(source);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
        urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 

        // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
        // from the HTTP call
        urlDrawable.drawable = result;

        // redraw the image by invalidating the container
        URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

        // For ICS. You could change your cointainer c (view) to a textView
        URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight() + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));

    }

    /***
     * Get the Drawable from URL
     * @param urlString
     * @return
     */
    public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
        try {
            InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                    + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
            return drawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } 
    }

    private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        return response.getEntity().getContent();
    }
}
```

}

I download images from Internet and displayed using TextView.
Original size image (350 * 500px).
But image is displayed on TextView a smaller size is (175 * 250px).
How to display the image in full size(350 * 500px) using TextView?
Samsung Galaxy SIII, Android 4.3 (1280*720).

Comment: put the code here and tell us exactly what you want to do .

Comment: Broad, overly general questions aren't likely to be answered.  Its not clear how this is even a programming question.  Take a look at the faq stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask