# How to show Text and Images in a TextView

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

This is the json response below from ifeng api.

[image]

Please help me how to show **text** object in a TextView including images in the middle.

Comment: You can't use textview to display images in middle of text.

Comment: @JyotiJK it is possible. Please check this answer. Thank you.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442725/1636610

Answer (score 2):

Use webwiev and load following json response(text witch are in html form) on webview.

Answer (score 2):

Try This
First pars that data ,then get text from **text param**

After getting the ***HTML text*** You need to use *Html.fromHtml()*

If your you are targeting  **< Android Nougat**

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("PUT YOUR HTML CODE HERE"));
```

If your you are targeting  **>= Android Nougat**

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("PUT YOUR HTML CODE HERE", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

**Note:-**

*To distinguish between Android versions use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N*

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Accept the answer ,so its helpful  to other member whose search for same.

Comment: This helps but partially. Does not help with the actual problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(...))`, then using html tags in `...`, but you need to implement `Html.ImageGetter`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442725/1636610

Comment: This link is more convenient & is working. Please check this answer. Thank you. stackoverflow.com/a/7442725/1636610

Comment: The answer that you suggest is more clearing, I'll change the reference link in my answer to this one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can show image in textview as drawable like below -

```
tvTitle.setText("Hi");
tvTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);//it will show icon image on left side of the text on tvTitle text view.
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20898900